# "I don't think there's someone home." vs "I don't think there's anyone home."

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, negation

I saw this question on a test:

> "I don't think there's _________ home."

One has to put a word in the empty space. So I thought to myself: `someone` or `anyone`?

On one hand, my first reaction was to say `"I don't think there's anyone home."` because negative and question sentences are usually made with `"any"`.

On the other hand, there are two simple sentences in the big one: `"I don't think"` and `"there's ______ home"`. And usually, the second sentence is in postive form (like in "Tell me *where the car is*."). So it must be `"I don't think there's someone home."`. Since the question was on a test, there's only one possible answer but I feel that both are correct (with a slight difference in meaning). The question was independent, there were no surrounding sentences to give context. Which one is the correct choice and why?

Answer (score 1):

A. "I don't think there's anyone home."

Because **we do not know how many people are "at home"**. Someone would be specifically meaning just one person.

> **Anyone, anybody and anything** are **indefinite pronouns**. We use anyone, anybody and anything to refer to both an open, unlimited set of things or people and specific things or people. We use them with a singular verb: Ref [C.E.D](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/anyone-anybody-or-anything?q=anyone)

> **someone;** pronoun; used to refer to a single person when you do not know who they are or when it is not important who they are:

Someone was walking towards the house